# identify -verbose returns Imagemagick version instead of image properites

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have this weird issue with Imagemagick.

Following the example usage instructions from imagemagick.org:

```
$identify = exec("identify $original_file");
```

This command gives output similar to the following:

> rose.jpg JPEG 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.36KB 0.000u 0:00.000

And it does which is fine.

This next command should give a big long list of all the different properties:

```
$identify = exec("identify -verbose $original_file");
```

but instead this is what I get:

> string(79) "  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-01
>   www.imagemagick.org"

I get this regardless of the image. There's nothing in the docs about it defaulting to the version if it can't find anything, and there are no errors in the logs, so I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Can you test the command in command line?

Comment: From the command line I get the image properties!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the example on this page http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php the version is the last line output from the command. I assume it is somehow overwriting the other information when you are using the variable.

```
echo "<pre>";
system("identify -verbose $original_file");
echo "</pre>";
```

This should output the information to the screen; what does it display?

EDIT
I found this works:

```
$original_file = "input.jpg";
$identify = exec("identify -verbose $original_file", $path);
print_r($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest you try adding an extra parameter to the `exec()` that captures the output, like this:

```
<?php
   $identify = exec("identify -verbose copyright.jpg",$output);
   var_dump($output);
?>
```

**Sample Output**

```
array(88) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "Image: copyright.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "  Mime type: image/jpeg"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "  Class: DirectClass"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "  Geometry: 10x12+0+0"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "  Units: Undefined"
  [6]=>
  string(15) "  Type: Palette"
  [7]=>
  string(22) "  Endianess: Undefined"
  [8]=>
  string(18) "  Colorspace: sRGB"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "  Depth: 8-bit"
  [10]=>
  string(16) "  Channel depth:"
  [11]=>
  string(14) "    red: 8-bit"
  [12]=>
  string(16) "    green: 1-bit"
  [13]=>
  string(15) "    blue: 1-bit"
```